# How do I get data out of a JSON object on javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have some Javascript/jQuery code that returns a JSON object and prints it in a HTML div. How can I access specific values of a JSON object in Javascript?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#question').on('submit', function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        var query = $('#request').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "durhamServer.php?".concat(query),
            success: function(result) {
                $("#response").html("<p>" + result + "</p>");
        }});
    });
});
```

Result in this case is the JSON object I want and for example, it comes out with

```js
{
    "durhamResponse": *response,
    "twitterResponse": *response
}
```

`*response` is a response from the server. How can I get `*response` as a value? 
It doesn't work when I try and `html result[0]` or `html result["durhamResponse"]`.

How do I access the values in the JSON object?

Comment: what does `result["durhamResponse"]` print on console?

Comment: What you say you've tried is extremely unclear. Show **properly formatted code** of what you tried and explain how it doesn't work

Comment: try result.data. if it doesn't work, log result and look to his structure.

Comment: give `dataType : 'json'`

Comment: @gurvinder372 it should print `undefined` because the property `"durhamResponse"` is not defined for the string object.

Answer (score 0):

THe [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) function parses JSON into a JavaScript object.

You want to use something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "durhamServer.php?".concat(query),
    success: function(result) {
        var parsedResult = JSON.parse(result);
        $("#response").html("<p>" + parsedResult.durhamResponse + "</p>");
    }
});
```

Comment: `jQuery.ajax(...)` is very likely to do the JSON processing automatically. This doesn't seem like a plausible answer

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `result` to an object by using `var resultObj = JSON.parse(result)`

JSON functions should natively be available in all [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=json)

Answer (score 0):

var jsonObject = JSON.parse(result);

You can easily test this in any browsers javascriptconsole:

console.log(JSON.parse('{"test": 1}'));

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$.ajax({
   method: "GET", 
   url: "durhamServer.php?".concat(query),  
   dataType: "json",//just to be sure
   success: function(result) {
       $("#response").html("<p>" + result.durhamResponse + "</p>");
   }
});
```

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations (why it solve the issue, where was the mistake, etc...)